# Converting RTF Files to DOCX and PDF Files on Python-Django and linux server

Tags: python, linux, pdf, docx, rtf

Is there any way to accurately convert RTF Files to PDF and DOC files on linux server with Python ? I have gone through a number of **past questions** and here is what I concluded :

1. The **libreoffice command line** converter is not accurate for my PDF and it does not work at all for DOC.
2. Python libraries like **PyWin32** work on Windows. I would have to make scripts and host it separately on Windows Server to work with Windows/Microsoft environment. Although I am not sure if it's worth giving it a try ?
3. There are .NET libraries like **Aspose.words** which will do the work but they are way too costly for a startup.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See pandoc and pypandoc as well. https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/

Comment: Hi @jlandercy. Thanks for your comment. However, when I tried it I encountered this error :
Invalid input format! Got "rtf" but expected one of these: commonmark, creole, docbook, docx, epub, fb2, gfm, haddock, html, jats, json, latex, man, markdown, markdown_github, markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki, muse, native, odt, opml, org, rst, t2t, textile, tikiwiki, twiki, vimwiki

which means it does not support rtf conversions in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per suggestions and further research by me, I concluded that it is best to implement the 2nd option mentioned in my question itself because of it's balance between a quality solution and being cost optimal. Although, utilities like libreoffice, latex etc. would do the work on linux but none of them are as accurate and real as a MS Word generated report. For my usecase, I implemented a separate Flask API to run on a windows server with MS Office license on it. It contains just a couple of endpoints, taking RTF file as input, and generating PDF and DOCX each.